# I need a method to run scripts in parallel on python. Is subprocessing the way to go or are there other methods worth looking into?

Tags: python, subprocess

So i have a big script that i had to optimize as well as cut in separate parts:
Let's say we now have 3 scripts called S1.py, S2.py and S3.py.
The script used to run through them straight with S1 and S2 both taking about 2mins to run and S3 about 15min.

I split them so i could access the results of S1 and S2 without needing to wait for S3. Now that I'm optimizing I'm wondering if it's possible to have a script that launches S1 and S2 in two subprocesses and waits for both scripts to be done before it runs S3 (who needs the results from S1 and S2).

Is subprocess.popen() the right way to go? or am I supposed to use threading in this situation? What other methods are available to achieve this goal?

Comment: you can modularize your code in S1 and S2 then use processpoolexecutor. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: Seems interesting but the problem i'm facing is it needs to be synchronous to a certain extent to launch S3 once both S1 and S2 are done, and i've already modularized them it seemed to make more sense to have them available independently @Epsi95

Comment: check, I have given one simple example

Comment: It's certainly _possible_, yes. Is it _ideal_? That depends on circumstances that haven't been described. If your process has expensive initialization, `exec()`ing a new interpreter can require that initialization to be done multiple times, whereas `fork()`ing off a subprocess can reuse all the in-memory state that's already finished in the parent process.

Comment: Really, though, I'm not sure that there's enough information given to make this an objective question rather than a subjective "best practices" type.

Comment: (Similarly, whether you should use threading depends on whether the GIL is held during the slow parts; if your process is I/O bound, or the slow logic is in C libraries that release the GIL while they work, threading may be fine -- and threading certainly makes it far easier to efficiently pass data to work on, or post-completion results, around between your parallel components).

Comment: Alright I've tested it with different sleep times and indeed it seems to work just as you said! I'm going to try to set it up with my actual modules now and I'll tell you if it worked out then, should take about 20-25min @Epsi95

Comment: Thanks for the input @CharlesDuffy , that's why i came on here to ask how people work through this, i haven't found anything to make me think i should use one method over another. The input for my program is taken from a client-side form which is fairly simple, but also uses an excel than can get thick (hundreds to tens of thousands of lines) so i wasn't too sure what to do. But the length of the excel is th main reason for the lengthy process of S3 that has to apply multiple linear regressions to all the data.

Comment: I don't think parallelism is going to have any significant benefit even given what little you have described. Given the timings of S1,S2 ~ 2min and S3 ~ 15min, running S1 and S2 in parallel is just going to reduce the *absolutely theoretically ideal* time from 19min (2+2+15) to 17min (max(2, 2) + 15). In reality, you will be paying some *performance* for orchestrating S1 and S2 and shipping data to/from them, and some *maintenance* for setting this up. Expect less than 10% speedup but much more complicated code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well considering certains aspects of my program, sometimes the client will have the right to interrupt the process between S1/S2 and S3 so in certain(although rare) conditions it may represent a 50% time reduction. But indeed when all 3 processes will be running the time saved will be quite smaller in comparison.

Comment: @Epsi95 it ended up working out with the ProcessPoolExecutor so thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

you learn more about it here https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

def s1():
    return 1

def s2():
    return 2

def s3(x,y):
    return x+y

def foo(f):
    return f()

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 3) as executor:
        results = executor.map(foo, [s1, s2])
        # now that we have the results
        print(s3(*results)) #3

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: How about at least some basic explanation? ``ProcessPoolExecutor`` hardly is the silver bullet for all concurrency/parallelism/synchronisation problems.